# How I am create a calendar in android 2.3 with syncronization?

Tags: android, calendar, android-2.3-gingerbread

I create a new calender with this code. Android 2.3.5

```
public long CreateNewCalendar(String nameSchedule) {
    try{
        ContentValues calendar = new ContentValues();
        calendar.put("_sync_account", nameSchedule); // My account
        calendar.put("_sync_account_type", "com.google");
        // calendar.put("_sync_id", 1); // null
        calendar.put("name", nameSchedule);
        calendar.put("displayName", nameSchedule);
        calendar.put("hidden", 0);
        calendar.put("color", 0xFF008080);
        calendar.put("access_level", 700);
        calendar.put("selected", 1); // 0
        calendar.put("sync_events", 1);
        // calendar.put("createdByCategory", 0); //Doesn't work on Motorola
        // Droid / Milestone
        calendar.put("timezone",  TimeZone.getDefault().getID());
        calendar.put("ownerAccount", nameSchedule);
        Uri calendarUri = Uri.parse(CalendarBase);
        Uri insertCalendarUri = ActivitySource.getContentResolver().insert(calendarUri, calendar);
        return ContentUris.parseId(insertCalendarUri);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        return -1;
    }
}
```

The calendar has successfully been created as I can see it in the calendar app. But after restart the mobile phone, the calendar no longer exists. What is happening?

Answer (score 0):

Do not use special character like '-,$' etc in name, ownerAccount and _sync_account. All will go fine :)